# HttpClient.execute getting error

Tags: android, wifi, httpresponse

I try work this out for some day and I just can't figured out. I am programem for android and have class that get data from server. Everything works well if I am connected to WiFi, but if I turned WiFi off to Mobile connection it works only on few phones. (Works on Galaxy Note, don't work on Galaxy Nexus and Galaxy 2)

code is very simple:

```
public void execute(DSRESTCommand command) throws DBXException {
    HttpClient client = null;

    HttpUriRequest method = CreateRequest(command);
    client = getHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
    setSessionIdentifier(response);
    throwExceptionIfNeeded(response)
    String s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

I tested this in debug mode and it turs it out that `client` and `command` are identical when it works and when it does not.

Only different that I can see in debug mode is `response`
string s whit WiFi on (and on Galaxy Note)look like :

```
 {"result":["Cube tree loaded ...  size: 3657",[60,63,120,109,108,32,118,...
```

whit WiFi off it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE wml PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.1//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml_1.1.xml">

<wml>
    <card id="FEHLER" title="ERROR">
       <p>
        The requested item could not be loaded <br/>
        Wrong MIME-Type
       <do type="prev" label="back">
           <prev/>
       </do>

       </p>
      </card>
</wml>
```

Can anyone know why this happend ? Please help me out.

Comment: yes and I dont Know what that mean. Can you help me?

Comment: You should search how you can set `Content-Type` header in your request. For example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/HttpGetandHttpPost.htm

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I still dont understand why it works whit WiFi and not whit Mobile connection. If I understand correctly if I had set Content-Type in reader wrong it wouldn't work on WiFi, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem to my question. I will post it for those who has similar problem.

It turned up to be the problem in mobile settings. All I have to do was delete Proxy from my APN in phone